# Using functions with String.replaceAll in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
<cffunction name="foo">
     <cfargument name="default">
     <cfoutput>#ARGUMENTS.default#</cfoutput>
     <cfreturn ARGUMENTS.default />
</cffunction>

<cfset LOCAL.derp = "((bar))" />
<cfset LOCAL.derp = LOCAL.derp.replaceAll("\(\((.*)\)\)", foo('$1')) />
<cfoutput>#LOCAL.derp#</cfoutput>
```

The output I am expecting is `bar bar` however I am getting `$1 bar`. How can this be done in ColdFusion9?

Comment: I cannot help with regular expressions, but just fyi `replaceAll` is not a ColdFusion function. It is a method of the [`java.lang.String` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). (Modified question title)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The foo function is evaluated first and the string result of that function is what is subsequently passed to replaceAll, which has no idea its input was provided via a function.

[String.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a Java method which accepts a regex pattern string and a replacement string - you can't pass a callback function in directly.

A solution to this is to use the [cfRegex library](http://cfregex.net) I have created - this has [a Replace function](http://docs.cfregex.net/Replace.html) which lets you pass in a function to be executed against every match.

This could be used something like this:

```
<cfset Local.Derp = RegexReplace
    ( Pattern     = '\(\((.*)\)\)'
    , Text        = Local.Derp
    , Replacement = replaceWithG1AndOutput
    ) />

<cffunction name="replaceWithG1AndOutput" returntype="String" output=true>
    <!---
        Use Arguments.Match for "((bar))"
        or Arguments.Groups[1].Match for "bar"
    --->
    <cfoutput>#Arguments.Groups[1].Match#</cfoutput>
    <cfreturn Arguments.Groups[1].Match />
</cffunction>
```